# DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS is empty

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces, metrics

For one of my 11.2g databases, `select * from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics` *returns no rows*.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many tablespaces are in the database? There is a bug where that view stops working if there's too many rows in dba_tablespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically caused by:

[Bug 18921384 - DBA_TABLESPACE_USAGE_METRICS VIEW DOES NOT RETURN ROWS WHEN DB_FILES LIMIT IS REACHED](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1903251.1)

To verify:

```
show parameter db_files

select count(*) from v$datafile;
```

Then increase `db_files` if needed or upgrade to a newer version where it is fixed.

Another possible cause:

[Bug 16317020 - Records missing from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics (Doc ID 16317020.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=16317020.8)

Also fixed in newer version, and one-off patch is also available.

Comment: Increasing the db_files parameter fixed the issue. The parameter was actually one higher than the count returned by 

select count(*) from v$datafile;

However, I upped the db_files parameter by 5 just to see what would happen and it fixed the issue.